# When can どうも be used as 'hello'?

Tags: nuances

I noticed this on few occasions. Unfortunately, I can't remember exact situations.

I want to clarify if どうも in a role of 'hello' is a shortened version of some longer phrase or just a phrase on its own. When is it okay to use it? Does it have any hidden nuance?

Comment: 住田 幾子　[日本語のあいさつことば：「どうも」のはたらきについて](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110000993875)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you don't want to or can't read the article Yang linked to, it begins by quoting two senses listed in the [日本国語大辞典]{にほんこくごだいじてん} which I will reproduce here in Japanese and translation:

> ④感謝したり詫びたりする気持ちを含む挨拶（あいさつ）に用いる。内容も省略し、「どうもどうも」と重ねて用いることも多い。（以下、用例略。）
>
> ⑤あいまいな、または安易な挨拶のことばとして用いる（以下、用例略。）

And my translation:

> (4) Used as a greeting that include feelings of gratitude and apology. Frequently, both the contents [for which one is grateful or apologizing] are omitted and the word is repeated as "dōmo dōmo" (following usage examples omitted). (5) Used as a greeting ambiguously or lightly.

Comment: So, basically, I can use it as 'hi' and to say sorry and there is no hidden meaning and nuance there, right?

Comment: @dimadesu not sure what you mean by hidden nuance, but picking the right greeting while straying away from おはようございます and こんにちは can get pretty complex pretty quickly. I think どうも could be a rather rude greeting in some social contexts. I seem to recall this being the standard greeting in dramas from unwanted stepchildren dropped off at the door. Normally, you'd probably want to throw on a 、よろしくお願いします afterwards to make it more respectable.